# Python list deleting item even though not explicitly told

Tags: python, list

So I had a very unusual problem with deleting elements from lists, I have recreated the problem in a much smaller and easier to understand format. Basically deleting an item from a list will delete the same item from a different list you have previously set equals to the original list outside of the main loop.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a

while True:
    print("a:", a)
    print("b:", b)
    c = int(input("delete"))
    del(a[c])
    print("a:", a)
    print("b:", b)
    break
```

This returns:

```
a: [1, 2, 3, 4]
b: [1, 2, 3, 4]
delete2 #the "2" is my input
a: [1, 2, 4]
b: [1, 2, 4]
>>>
```

I researched and saw a few things about shallow/deep copies, but i'm not too sure about that, if anyone could shed some more light that would be great

Comment: *"saw a few things about shallow/deep copies"* - and you're using **neither**. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: "....but i'm not too sure about that, if anyone could shed some more light that would be great", sorry if I've annoyed you, but thanks for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `a` and `b` are names of the same list (or more formally, references to the same object).

To create a name for a new list make a copy of it:

```
b = list(a)
# or
b = a[:]
```

This will create a new list containing the exact same members and is called shallow-copy.

A deep-copy is when you recursively copy the entire structure but it seems like its not needed here.

Comment: When someone actually gives an example of what he did that works and shows he bothered to try and understand, I think I'll contribute two minutes to explain. The duplicate target is not very good at the moment but I'm sure there are good duplicate targets.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, i'll look into the duplicate targets